# Image onload doesn't work sometimes

Tags: html, image, canvas, onload, drawimage

```
function rendercanvas()
{
    if(!window.isDirty && !gameover)
    {
        context.clearRect(0,0,window.innerWidth,1000);

        backofcardred = new Image();
        backofcardred.addEventListener('load', drawDealerStack);
        backofcardred.src = "graphics/backofcardred.jpg";// + '?' + (new Date()).getTime();


        backofcardblue = new Image();
        backofcardblue.addEventListener('load', drawClientStack);
        backofcardblue.src = "graphics/backofcardblue.jpg";// + '?' + (new Date()).getTime();


        context.beginPath();
        context.rect(100, 195, 100, 146);
        context.fillStyle = 'blue';
        context.fill();
        context.lineWidth = 1;
        context.strokeStyle = 'black';
        context.stroke();

        context.beginPath();
        context.rect(100, 343, 100, 146);
        context.fillStyle = 'red';
        context.fill();
        context.lineWidth = 1;
        context.strokeStyle = 'black';
        context.stroke();

        context.beginPath();
        context.fillStyle = 'black';
        context.strokeStyle = 'black';
        context.font = 'italic 30pt Calibri';
        var message = "Client Score:"+clientTally+" Dealer Score:"+dealerTally;
        context.fillText(message, 220,100);

        if(currentWinner!="")
        {

        }
    }

    if(window.isDirty && !gameover)
    {
        context.clearRect(0,0,window.innerWidth,1000);

        context.beginPath();
        context.fillStyle = 'black';
        context.strokeStyle = 'black';
        context.font = 'italic 30pt Calibri';
        var message = "Client Score:"+clientTally+" Dealer Score:"+dealerTally;
        context.fillText(message, 220,100);

        context.fillStyle = 'black';
        context.strokeStyle = 'black';
        context.font = 'italic 10pt Calibri';

        backofcardred = new Image();
        backofcardred.addEventListener('load', drawDealerStack);
        backofcardred.src = "graphics/backofcardred.jpg";// + '?' + (new Date()).getTime();


        backofcardblue = new Image();
        backofcardblue.addEventListener('load', drawClientStack);
        backofcardblue.src = "graphics/backofcardblue.jpg";// + '?' + (new Date()).getTime();


        if( clientwarareastack.cards[0] != null)
        {
            context.beginPath();
            context.rect(100,343,100,146);
            context.fillStyle = 'white';
            context.fill();
            context.lineWidth = 1;
            context.strokeStyle = 'white';
            context.stroke();
            context.beginPath();

            suitecharacter( clientwarareastack.cards[0] );
            var message = clientwarareastack.cards[0].rank + " " + suitUChar;
            context.fillText(message, 100+10, 343+25);
        }
        else
        {
            context.beginPath();
            context.rect(100, 343, 100, 146);
            context.fillStyle = 'red';
            context.fill();
            context.lineWidth = 1;
            context.strokeStyle = 'black';
            context.stroke();       
        }

        if( dealerwarareastack.cards[0] != null)
        {
            context.beginPath();
            context.rect(100,195,100,146);
            context.fillStyle = 'white';
            context.fill();
            context.lineWidth = 1;
            context.strokeStyle = 'white';
            context.stroke();   

            suitecharacter( dealerwarareastack.cards[0] );
            var message = dealerwarareastack.cards[0].rank + " " + suitUChar;
            context.fillText(message, 100+10, 195+25);
        }
        else
        {
            context.beginPath();
            context.rect(100, 195, 100, 146);
            context.fillStyle = 'blue';
            context.fill();
            context.lineWidth = 1;
            context.strokeStyle = 'white';
            context.stroke();       
        }

    }

    if(gameover)
    {
        context.clearRect(0,0,window.innerWidth,1000);
        context.fillText("GAME OVER. REFRESH THE PAGE TO START OVER.FINAL WINNER:"+finalwinner, 100+10, 195+25);
    }
}

function drawDealerStack() {
    context.beginPath();
    context.drawImage(backofcardblue, 100, 50);
    context.stroke();
}
function drawClientStack() {
    context.beginPath();
    context.drawImage(backofcardred, 100, window.originYclientstack);
    context.stroke();
}
```

`backofcardred` and `backofcardblue` sometimes do not render to the canvas. Most of time I see `backofcardred` and `backofcardblue` so the problem is intermittent. Uncommenting `// + '?' + (new Date()).getTime();` only makes the problem far worse. Is there anything that can be done to make sure the image loads every time? I'm not opposed to jQuery. I'm not sure yet why the problem is happening. Does anyone know why the image sometimes isn't drawn to the canvas?

Thank you for posting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't really see enough of your overall calling context to understand what might be going wrong.  As such, what I would recommend is some defensive coding that removes many sources of issues.  The main thing to do is to get rid of the global variables you are using for the cards.  If you happen to be calling `renderCanvas()` more than once or there's a scoping issue with those variables, then they may be getting overwritten while they are being used or go out of scope.  Removing the card global variables entirely will protect against that.  In addition, I've tried to remove a bunch of duplicate code with a few shared functions.

Changes:

1. Removed global variables for the cards by making them local variables.
2. Use `this` in the load callbacks.
3. Replace lots of duplicate code with shared local functions (not part of the potential solution, but makes code a lot cleaner).
4. Moved event handler functions to be local functions (no need to be global).

Changed code:

```
function rendercanvas() {
    function makeCards() {
        var backofcardred = new Image();
        backofcardred.addEventListener('load', drawDealerStack);
        backofcardred.src = "graphics/backofcardred.jpg";// + '?' + (new Date()).getTime();


        var backofcardblue = new Image();
        backofcardblue.addEventListener('load', drawClientStack);
        backofcardblue.src = "graphics/backofcardblue.jpg";// + '?' + (new Date()).getTime();
    }

    function drawRect(x, y, w, h, fill, width, stroke){
        context.beginPath();
        context.rect(x,y,w,h);
        context.fillStyle = fill;
        context.fill();
        context.lineWidth = width;
        context.strokeStyle = stroke;
        context.stroke();
    }

    function drawText(msg) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.fillStyle = 'black';
        context.strokeStyle = 'black';
        context.font = 'italic 30pt Calibri';
        context.fillText(msg, 220,100);
    }

    function drawDealerStack() {
        context.beginPath();
        context.drawImage(this, 100, 50);
        context.stroke();
    }

    function drawClientStack() {
        context.beginPath();
        context.drawImage(this, 100, window.originYclientstack);
        context.stroke();
    }

    if(!window.isDirty && !gameover)
    {
        context.clearRect(0,0,window.innerWidth,1000);
        makeCards();
        drawRect(100, 195, 100, 146, 'blue', 1, 'black');
        drawRect(100, 343, 100, 146, 'red', 1, 'black');
        drawText("Client Score:"+clientTally+" Dealer Score:"+dealerTally);


        if(currentWinner!="")
        {

        }
    }

    if(window.isDirty && !gameover)
    {
        context.clearRect(0,0,window.innerWidth,1000);
        drawText("Client Score:"+clientTally+" Dealer Score:"+dealerTally);
        makeCards();

        if( clientwarareastack.cards[0] != null)
        {
            drawRect(100,343,100,146, 'white', 1, 'white');
            context.beginPath();
            suitecharacter( clientwarareastack.cards[0] );
            var message = clientwarareastack.cards[0].rank + " " + suitUChar;
            context.fillText(message, 100+10, 343+25);
        }
        else
        {
            drawRect(100, 343, 100, 146, 'red', 1, 'black');
        }

        if( dealerwarareastack.cards[0] != null)
        {
            drawRect(100,195,100,146, 'white', 1, 'white');
            suitecharacter( dealerwarareastack.cards[0] );
            var message = dealerwarareastack.cards[0].rank + " " + suitUChar;
            context.fillText(message, 100+10, 195+25);
        }
        else
        {
            drawRect(100, 195, 100, 146, 'blue', 1, 'white');
        }

    }

    if(gameover)
    {
        context.clearRect(0,0,window.innerWidth,1000);
        context.fillText("GAME OVER. REFRESH THE PAGE TO START OVER.FINAL WINNER:"+finalwinner, 100+10, 195+25);
    }
}
```

Comment: With such good postings its hard to choose only one as my answer however this post has so many good pointers in it I think its going to get marked as the answer. Thank you for posting. I like the use of this for the onload function

Answer (score 1):

Actually the solution is more the `var` part. Please double check me, but it appears he's leaking `backofcardred` & `backofcardblue` into global scope causing the almost identical code on-top and on-bottom to misbehave.

Use image.onload:

```
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {
    // the image is fully loaded and ready to use
}
image.src = "yourImage.png";
```

Comment: The code is already doing `img.addEventListener("load", fn)` which works just fine.  There's no reason to use `.onload` instead of that.

Comment: @jfriend00 Actually the solution is more the `var` part of my answer.  Please double check me but it appears he's leaking backofcardred & backofcardblue into global scope causing the almost identical code on-top and on-bottom to misbehave.

Comment: Next time, if that's the point of your answer, then you should actually SAY that with words in your answer.  The way his code is written, `backofcardred` and `backofcardblue` need to be global in scope because they are used in other functions.  The code could be changed to not need these global variables, but I'm not seeing that as the source of an intermittent problem unless this code is getting called a bunch of times for different cards.

Comment: @jfriend00 Fair enough :)  I probably should have narratively said I am worried about a potential scoping issue.

Comment: I put in the var in front of image. I hadn't yet noticed those were belonging to the global scope. Thanks for the heads up on that. Using the onload is a little bit shorter I think if they both work the same way. I went with onload and added the var. I'm going to have to do some testing...

Comment: I moved the declaration of onload back inline as markE's example because the way I had things backofcardred and backofcardblue were coming up undefined in that scope. The variables are seen if onload is declared inline. It appears to be working right now.